# Is this formula in normal form prenex $(\forall x)(\exists y)(P(x) \land (\exists z)Q(y, z))$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In my course notes, this  $(\forall x)(\exists)z(P(x) \land (\exists z)Q(y, z))$ formula is said to be in `normal form prenex`. But, shouldn't al cuantors be in the back of the formula? I mean, I would expect this formula to be in the normal form prenex: $(\forall x)(\exists y)(\exists z)(P(x) \land Q(y, z))$

Comment: Terminology: "prenex normal form", "quantifier".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes prenex normal form must have all quantifiers at the front so what you said is correct.